# Balancing horizontally 2 TextViews and an ImageView between them according to text length

Tags: android-layout, android-constraintlayout, constraintlayout-barrier

[image]

- If Text1 is longer, than it should push everything to the right
- If Text2 is longer, than it should push everything to the left
- Otherwise, the arrow should be centered according to parent view
- If any TextView exceeds, thus the whole view exceeds the parent view, then it should be trimmed (ellipsize)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using `ConstraintLayout`. Create a packed horizontal chain, and use `wrap_content` plus *constrainedWidth* on each text view:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/image"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/image"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/left"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/right"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

If *both* text views have long text, you can control which one gets given space first by re-ordering the tags within the `ConstraintLayout`. This won't change how they're positioned; it will change only whether the left or right text stretches first.

Comment: `android:ellipsize` seems not to work.